# A new(?) analytic continuation for the Riemann zeta function.

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, analytic-continuation

While tweaking the definition for the Euler gamma constant I found that the following appears to be true:

$$\zeta(s)=\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{a^{s-1} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{a n} \frac{1}{k^s}-b^{s-1} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{b n} \frac{1}{k^s}}{a^{s-1}-b^{s-1}}$$

when $\Re(s)>0$, $a>0$ and $b>0$.

Can you prove it?

Comment: Associated Mathematica program: https://pastebin.com/7bC5S6c2

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ integers? Can they have any positive value? What is $n$?

Comment: What are $a,b?$, The  RHS has a finite number of terms

Comment: $a$ and $b$ can be rationals according to Mathematica, but I find it more logical for them to be integers. Oh no, I forgot to include the limit. $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: I included the limit now, that previously I forgot.

Comment: I see you added a limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$. This makes the expression trivially true. For any $a,b>0$, both sums on the right hand side just become $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: @JohnBarber Not for $\Re(s)>0$

Comment: @MatsGranvik True.

Comment: Of course fails for $s=1$, where $\zeta$ has a pole.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the AFE (approximate functional equation): $\zeta(s)=\sum_{k \le x}k^{-s}-\frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s}+O(x^{-\sigma})$ uniform in $\sigma \ge \sigma_0>0$ and valid for say $|t| < \pi x, s=\sigma+it$

Fixing $s, \Re s=\sigma >0$ and letting $n$ large enough so $x=an,bn$ satisfy the above, one has:

RHS($n$)=$\zeta(s)+O(n^{-\sigma})$ since the oscillating terms $a^{s-1}\frac{(an)^{1-s}}{1-s}-b^{s-1}\frac{(bn)^{1-s}}{1-s}$ obviously cancel out.

This implies the result by taking $n \to \infty$

Note that $a,b>0$ can be arbitrary fixed, not necessarily integral